# Make rows and columns dynamic so when adding a new row or column the chart automatically updates?

Tags: excel

In MS Excel if we want to make a chart then we have to select the data range.

Is there is any way that when new entries (row or column) are added then the chart updates automatically?

Comment: I have a chart that does that (at least for rows) and the data source is a `Table`.  I don't add columns, so can't report anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be challenging for stacked bar charts in Excel 2010.  Let's take the case of a simple table with some numbers:

```
            2016    2017
    Sam        3       4
    Fred       5       6
    Alice      3       4
```

Select the table, right-click on its tab, and select insert chart.  Choose stacked bar.  Then, choose switch Row/Column.  Now, if you go to Design | Select Data, you see a nice formula for the Chart Data Range.  If you insert a row, however, and add someone else, you get a discontinuous range and they are not included in the chart.  If, however, you first select your data, choose Insert | Table, and tell it it has headers, then you can insert a row, and have it included in the chart automatically as e.g. sales from an extra salesperson.

This happens only if two things occur:

1. It must be a table, and
2. It must be a continuous table range for your source data.  No skipping columns.  Perhaps it might work for a subset of a table.

If either is not true, it breaks it.  I would criticize the way it doesn't account for inserted rows, or the way it complains about chart data ranges being too complex and doesn't even show you the text of the chart data to let you edit it, if the columns are out of order (ok, I'm complaining), but while e.g. Libre Office calc lets you edit formulas even when they are complex, it never keeps track of inserted rows to add more data series.

If you use dynamic formulas for the chart, or named regions, it just converts them into cell range references, and fails to account for inserted rows.

Answer (score -1):

Create dynamic named ranges for the labels and each series, and edit the chart data to use these names.

An example for the named range is where the labels might be in column A, and some values in column B

```
=$B$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($A:$A))
```

which is defining a range starting at B2 and ending at the row in column B that corresponds to the last data row in the labels column A.

Add a named range for each series.

When pointing the chart to these names, be sure to preface it with the sheet name, even if you are on that sheet, something like

```
=Sheet1!2010Amounts
```

Comment: Hi @Bob Philips ...Can you please provide me some template that have two sheets having chart in first sheet and data in second sheet so that when i update in data then chart automatically updates.Thanks alot

Comment: I have already dynamic named ranges that automatically update if any row is added but i want some simple solution for that also so that i can get rid of specifying named range for each column.

Comment: I don';t think that you can. If you look at the Select Data Source dialog, you can see each series is individually defined, so you need a name for each AFAICS.

Comment: Regarding different sheets, make sure all of the ranges in the name refer to the data sheet not the active sheet, and use a workbook name reference in the chart ='myworkbook.xlsx'!myrangename

Comment: Tried to upvote again: wouldn't let me.  Tried to make the edit a comment: wouldn't let me.  It took a reputation point away for the downvote???